# How did Shocker get to the school so quickly?

Tags: marvel, marvel-cinematic-universe, spider-man-homecoming

In *Spider-Man: Homecoming*, Toomes realizes that Peter is Spider-Man in the car on the way to school for the dance. He did not pass on this information at least until Peter left the car. Peter then went inside and then ran out less than a minute later. Even giving him time to change, it couldn't have been five minutes between leaving the car and leaving the building. So how did Shocker get to the school to meet him?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Vulture and his group were planning "one last job" that night with a very specific time frame, it seems most likely that his group, or at least Schultz were just around the corner from the school or tailing Vulture in the car and were going to meet up with him after he dropped them off. On top of that it was on the route anyway and if on a common part of the route they could have been driving past and he just asked them to drop Schultz off.

> **Peter:** Sir, you don’t have to drive us.
>
> **Toomes:** No, no, it’s not a big deal. I’m going out of town. It’s right on my way.
>
> **Doris:** He’s always coming and going.
>
> **Toomes:** Last time.
>
> <sub>*Spider-Man: Homecoming*</sub>